# Bash Scripting - user interaction when script launched from Systemd

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I have been google searching a lot but I'm not finding any info to help me with my task.  Maybe its not possible.  I am working with Raspbian distro on a raspberry Pi but I think its relevant to anyone bash scripting.

I have created udev rules and a systemd service that execute a bash script I wrote when the system detect a google phone plugged into usb (for example plugging in a nexus 4, 5 6P, etc).  And it all works.  You plug in a phone and my script will execute and use fastboot to obtain the device product name and then flash the appropriate twrp image to the recovery partition on phone (twrp being a custom made recovery os for the phone).

If I execute the bash script manually at terminal you will have user interaction.  Echoing info and what not.  I have a 5sec count down timer gives the user the chance to stop execution after device is detected.  That works too.

My problem is this:  When the script is executed by systemd its in it own virtual terminal or whatever so if your at a console you wont see anything from the script and the script cant see any user input (e.g. key stroke) to cancel out.

I want to know, is there a way if your sitting at a console for my script to start displaying the 5 sec countdown warning and allow the user to cancel?

I currently have the raspberry pi setup in headless mode so it boots to console and thats it.  It does not start any graphical environment.  And I usually ssh into the raspberry PI to work with it.  So when I ssh in and execute the w command I see my tty is /pts/0.

Is it possible to get my script to output and read for any key stroke from a current console?  I hope that makes sense.

I ended up making a function in my script that I can call to echo out to all active, open tty's but I have no idea how to read in.  And I figure there is probably a much more elegant way to achieve what I am doing.  Thanks in advance for any help or advice anyone could provide.  I'll put code and outputs below.

Paul.

```
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
pi       tty1                      18:22    1:08m  1.18s  0.92s -bash
pi       pts/0    fe80::187c:321f: 18:49    1.00s  2.98s  0.05s w
```

My udev rule

```
# Google
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE:="0666", GROUP:="plugdev", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="load-fastboot-flasher.service"
```

My systemd service unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Google Device TWRP Recovery
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=idle
User=pi
ExecStart=/home/pi/fastboot-twrp/fastboot-twrp-flash.sh > /dev/null &
StandardOutput=console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And finally my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

######################################################################################
# Our function that performs the flash after a device was detected.
######################################################################################
fastboot-test() {
 GOOGLEDEVICENAME=`fastboot getvar product 2>&1 | grep "product:" | awk '{print $2}'`
 if [[ "$GOOGLEDEVICENAME" != "" ]]; then
    echoall "Device Product_Name: $GOOGLEDEVICENAME"
    if [ ! -d "$GOOGLEDEVICENAME" ]; then
       # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY doesn't exist.
       echoall "Error!  Device folder & recovery image dont exist.  Aborting!"
       echoall ""
       echoall "Please create a folder using the same product name as your device in the folder"
       echoall "that this script resides in and place your twrp image in this new folder."
       echoall "e.g. for a Nexus 4 make a folder called mako with your twrp image inside it."
       echoall ""
       exit 1
    fi
    cd $GOOGLEDEVICENAME
    echoall "Selecting twrp image: " $PWD/twrp*
    sleep 1
    echoall ""
    fastboot flash recovery $PWD/twrp*
    echoall ""
    echoall "twrp recovery image flash complete!"
    echoall "Enjoy your fishing.... ;-)"
    echoall ""
 else
    echoall "No connected Google devices"
 fi
}

######################################################################################
# Our function to print output to all currently open consoles (e.g. type w a terminal to see users)
######################################################################################
echoall() {
 for PTS in $(w |grep -o pts/.) ; do echo $1 $2 $3 >>/dev/$PTS; echo $1 $2 $3 >>/home/pi/load-fastboot-flasher.log; done
}



######################################################################################
# START
######################################################################################
#set +x
echoall ""
echoall "$(date)"
echoall ""
echoall "Google device detected.  Press C then ENTER to cancel TWRP recovery flash in 5 seconds"
COUNT=5
while (( COUNT > 0 ))
 #This is our 5 sec timer.
 do
   read -t 1 -n 1 -r
   if [[ $REPLY == ^[Cc]$ ]]; then
      Exit 0
   fi
   sleep 1
   (( COUNT -- ))
   echoall $COUNT
 done
echoall ""
echoall ""
#set -x

DETECTED=`fastboot devices | awk '{print $2}'`
if [[ "$DETECTED" == "fastboot" ]]; then

  #Save the current working directory
  RESTOREPATH=`pwd`

  #Change the current working directory to the directory that this script resides in
  cd $(dirname $(readlink -f $0))
  echoall "changed working directory to: "$PWD
  echoall ""
  #

  echoall "Device detected: Yes"
  fastboot-test
  cd $RESTOREPATH
  echoall "changed working directory to: "$PWD
  echoall ""
  echoall "### END TWRP FLASH ###"
  echoall ""
  for PTS in $(w |grep -o pts/.) ; do echo -ne '\n' >>/dev/$PTS; done
  exit
else
  echoall "Error! Fastboot not properly detecting Google device."
fi
```

Comment: You might consider [systemd user mode](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User).  The piece I don't know about is how to plug in udev in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: you can't. and if you could, you shouldn't.

Writing to all terminals is easy; `wall` will do that for you. However, there is already a process reading your terminal input and that is your shell (`bash` if everything is default). So if you want a second process to read from the same terminal, you will  have the problem that some characters you type will go to the script ans some to shell. Perhaps an example will demonstrate the problem:

You're typing `rm -rf /a` in your ssh session and a phone gets connected. Almost everything is caught by the shell, but your script catches the `a` and when you hit enter, you'll get the warning that it is dangerous to operate recursively on /.

You might want to explore other options; for example a dancer2 web application.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  Yeah I figured its probably not a wise move to do and your example jsut proved how dangerous it can be.  Thank you.

Comment: I just had another thought.  Could I have my script create a new tty and switch to that and then when complete switch back to the original tty?

Comment: But that creates the same problem. Assumming that it would be possible , whether it is two processes reading from a terminal or two terminals reading from what you type, the problem is the same.